# How to reverse from horizontal to vertical (mobile view)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to reverse view for mobile but can't understand where exactly should I make changes. Got code from YouTube lesson and changed it for my project. I want to move left side (text) to the top and right side (image) to the bottom when open on mobile. I'm learning so don't judge me too much, please!

```js
let zSpacing = -1000,
  lastPos = zSpacing / 5,
  $frames = document.getElementsByClassName('frame'),
  frames = Array.from($frames),
  zVals = []

window.onscroll = function() {
  let top = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    delta = lastPos - top
  lastPos = top

  frames.forEach(function(n, i) {
    zVals.push((i * zSpacing) + zSpacing)
    zVals[i] += delta * -4
    let frame = frames[i],
      transform = `translateZ(${zVals[i]}px)`,
      opacity = zVals[i] < Math.abs(zSpacing) / 1.9 ? 1 : 0
    frame.setAttribute('style', `transform: ${transform}; opacity: ${opacity}`)
  })
}

window.scrollTo(0, 1)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --index: calc(1vw + 1vh);
  --gutter: 30px;
  --small-side: 16;
  --big-side: 26;
  --depth: 1800px;
  --transition: .75s cubic-bezier(.075, .5, 0, 1);
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: calc(var(--index) * .8);
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.75;
  height: var(--depth);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.gallery {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
}

.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: var(--transition), opacity .75s ease;
  will-change: transform;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.frame-media {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(var(--index) * var(--big-side));
  height: calc(var(--index) * var(--small-side));
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: orange;
}

.frame-media_right {
  left: calc(var(--big-side) / 2 * var(--index) + var(--gutter));
}

.frame-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
}

.text-left>* {
  position: relative;
  right: 25%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="frame frame_bg">
      <div class="frame__content text-left text-up">
        <h2>hello hello hello hello</h2>
        <div class="frame-media frame-media_right frame-media_down"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frame">
      2
    </div>

    <div class="frame">
      3
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code needs a lot of adjustment but I'm just not gonna do that. Instead and since you are learning, I will simply explain to you how to make a responsive design.

1- It starts from your HMTL **structure**. put you element in order and remember when it goes from horizontal to vertical, it will happen according to your HTML order.

2- Set parent `display` to `flex` with `row direction` for the `flex`.

3- Add your `media query` for mobile and set parent `flex-direction` to `column` in it.

that's it.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


}

.container div, h2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div">div1</div>
    <h2 class="text">some text</h2>
    <div class="div">div2</div>
    <div class="div">div3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I tried to play with "frame-media_right" and try calc it a different way, but it was not necessary. The answer was on the surface, and you showed me the right direction. Now it's looks like I wanted, thank you, again!